# No logging for programs opened from batch file

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, log4net

I wrote a wpf program, which uses log4net to generate a log file when the program starts. It works fine when I open the program.exe.
If I open the program from a batch file (as administrator) with "%~dp0\program.exe", the wpf window works as usual, but no log file is generated.

Comment: What does your log4net configuration look like?

Comment: When you load the log configuration, are you loading a file using a relative path? The working (current) directory will be different when started by a batch file.

Comment: Thanks @stuartd, you were completly right! I am using  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory now and it works like a charm.